# Pystache without escaping (unescaped)

Tags: python, django, templating, pystache

I'm using pystache to render the templates. I'm getting `&amp;` in the output when I render context variables having &. How can get rid of `&amp;` where I need & . 
Same thing is happening with django templating as well

```
>>> pystache.render('The URL {{URL}}', {'URL': 'http://google.com?a=3&b=3'})
u'The URL http://google.com?a=3&amp;b=3'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### To prevent escaping use triple braces `{{{var}}}`

To prevent escaping, use triple braces, `{{{URL}}}` instead of double braces `{{URL}}`

```
>>> pystache.render('The URL {{{URL}}}', {'URL': 'http://google.com?a=3&b=3'})
u'The URL http://google.com?a=3&b=3'
```

I've tested this on the most recent release as of today, version `0.5.4`

### Mustache Documentation

Since Pystache is a Mustache implementation in Python, you can use Mustache's documentation as pointers.

> All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return
>   unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}.

source: https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Comment: Can you please tell me where it is documented ?

Comment: The best I could find: https://github.com/defunkt/pystache/blob/master/pystache/tests/examples/unescaped.mustache

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago [they've got such suggestion](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache/issues/32).

There is **auxillary `escape` option** of `Renderer` class initializer. This option accepts function that operates on strings. Default is `cgi.escape(s, quote=True)`.

So when you write:

```
import pystache
rend = pystache.Rendered(escape=lambda s: s)
rend.render(your_obj)
```

you've got unascaped values without tripple braces in template.

See [docs](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache/blob/cae37b1fb44912f42a129ca2764419c495b05efd/pystache/renderer.py#L64) on `Rendered` class

Comment: My answer targeted non-HTML use cases. Because tripple curly braces in such templates hurts my eyes )). So, why not using simple double braces?